# Accumulating money in a company and withdrawing as dividends

Tags: taxes, income-tax, singapore, spain

Let's assume that I incorporated a company and started providing consulting services for a fee; payments are transferred to a company's bank account. Once a year I distribute accumulated money as dividends to myself.
Would this be legit?

Comment: Legit assumes you're asking about some law. What law exactly are you referring to? In what country?

Comment: @littleadv, what country should I reder to if the company is in one country, and I stay in another?

Comment: @lattedsit: You should mention both and say which is which.

Comment: @BrenBarn, ok... let's assume that the company is in Singapore and I stay in Spain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@littleadv is right, this depends on your country. Furthermore, this is likely to depend on the type of business you own (in the US: LLC, S-corp, C-corp). In some countries you have to provide yourself a minimum wage if you are classified as a major shareholder and work for the company. When there is a minimum level of wage you have to pay yourself the tax rate on wages is typically higher than on dividends. The wage you then receive is taxed in line with normal wage taxation rules. Above the minimum wage you can pay yourself in dividends.

Comment: As far as I understand Singapore doesn't have a minimum wage level. I wonder if this means that I can set my wages to 1$ (or just 0)?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Singaporean law. If you call your tax agency then you know for sure.

Comment: if this site is not for answers, what is its supposed purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are making quite a bit of assumptions without clarifying what you are trying to achieve.

As a non-resident you cannot incorporate a sole proprietorship in Singapore. You have to be citizen. Alternatively you can register a company that has its own norms like minimum number of directors and some being Singapore national, etc.

As you are paying dividend and not salary to yourself, the company will be required to pay taxes on gains. So all consulting money is gain as there is no expense. The balance when you transfer to Spain would potentially get taxed as income to you subject to DTAA

Comment: Well... my primary goal is to register a company and "get" a permanent job (as many bureaucrates get paranoid when they hear a word "freelancer"). And Singapore looks like a place where it can be done quite easily. As far as I understand, I can incorporate a company in Singapore using a nominee director? And the corporate tax is 17%, exempt for the first 3 years?